# dhclient.conf missed on centos

Tags: networking, centos, dhcp

on centos 6 I need take the values from a dhcp server:

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:50:56:27:0E:C8
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=20924b21-e92a-4944-a054-06d1967155c1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
PEERDNS=yes
```

dhclient take only IP (not gw, not dns, not hostname).

There is not any dhclient.conf not even an example file.

Comment: Is there /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.cfg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create

```
/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf
```

and put these lines:

```
send host-name = gethostname();
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;

ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want the gateway/router:-

```
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset,
interface-mtu;
```